# I am using `react-i18next` for translation and I need to give style to a certain part of string, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I have this string in my `en.json` file `"outOf100": "{{val}} out of 100"` and I am using it like this `{t('outOf100', {val: <h6>22.45</h6>})}` in JSX.

Can anyone please tell me how to make the `val` look like an `h6` whereas all other part of string as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Trans component to format your string with different HTML-tags. It will look something like this:

```
  //inside React-component
  return (
    <Trans i18nKey="outOf100">
      <h6>{{val}}</h6> out of 100.
    </Trans>
  );

  //in en.json
  "outOf100": "<0>{{val}}</0> out of 100"
```

For more info about the Trans component, please [see the docs.](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component)